# gsettings: command not found

Tags: gnome, bash, desktop-background

I am trying to create a script, which will change the wallpaper automatically when run.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/
rm -r ~/.wallpaper
mkdir .wallpaper
cd ~/.wallpaper

wget https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080
USER=$(whoami)
PATH="file:///home/$USER/.wallpaper/1920x1080"
echo $PATH
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$PATH"
```

But when i do `./change_wallpaper.sh` I get the echo correctly, but then

> ./change_wallpaper.sh: line 12: gsettings: command not found

However, when I run the same command from terminal, it executes fine and wallpaper is getting changed.

When I run `whereis gsettings` it tells

> gsettings: /usr/bin/gsettings /usr/share/man/man1/gsettings.1.gz

Why is it showing `gsettings: command not found` when I execute from script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you change the `PATH` in your script. This reserved variable is used to locate executable files. Use another variable.

Same with `USER`: it is reserved as well and already contains the current user, i.e. you do not need to set `USER=$(whoami)`.

In general, when creating variables in shell scripts it is a good idea to use lowercase names. Usually, predefined variables (like `HOME`, `USER`, `PATH`) are all UPPERCASE and a simple way to avoid overwriting them is to use lowercase names in own scripts. Or use some prefix, e.g. `MY_PATH`, `MY_USER` etc.

Comment: That did solve my problem. I was already aware of the PATH Environment variable. But, was not aware changing it in script, will make my commands to fail. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Your script won't work for everyone.**  The variable you set for home for your user will be incorrect for people who have their `HOME` location in a different place from `/home/user`.  For instance, my home location for my personal space is `/home/user/l/j/ljames`.

Instead of setting the path to be `"file:///home/$USER/.wallpaper/1920x1080"` you should more correctly change it to `"file:///$HOME/.wallpaper/1920x1080"`.  The variable `$HOME` is already expanded to the full home space of the user.

**Your script will work if with these changes:**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/
rm -r ~/.wallpaper
mkdir .wallpaper
cd ~/.wallpaper

wget https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080
# USER=$(whoami) This line isn't neccesary.)    
path="file:///$HOME/.wallpaper/1920x1080"
echo $path
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$path"
```

**A more efficient example is:**

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -d ~/.wallpaper ] && mkdir ~/.wallpaper
cd ~/.wallpaper
wget -O 1920x1080 https://source.unsplash.com/random/
path="file:///$HOME/.wallpaper/1920x1080"
rm ~/.cache/wallpaper/*
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$path"
```

**The explaining of the lines are:**

```
Line #1:  Create wallpaper directory if it doesn't exist.
Line #2:  Move to the folder.
Line #3:  Overwrite the current file with the new wallpaper.
Line #4:  Set the pathname variable.
Line #5:  Removed the Wallpaper cache for image change detection.
Line #6:  Active the new wallpaper.
```

Comment: I was not aware, there is a HOME variable and we can have home directory after many directories from /home/. In the first line where we are creating a directory there is only one `[` and two `]` why is that syntax like this?

Comment: @PerlDuck That's correct... I fixed it.

Comment: @SaranSankaran An ordinary user's home directory _usually_ (and by convention) is right below `/home` but it can be anywhere else. Especially _technical_ users often have their home directory elsewhere. For example the user `www-data` (created and used by apache) has `/var/www` as their home directory.